# How do I use python or jq to merge multiple JSON files with uniform columns into one CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv, merge, jq

I am trying to make Primary Source American Law more American with Disabilities Act (ADA), more compliant for my Study.

The technical question is in the topic.

The source files I am using are found here: https://www.courtlistener.com/api/bulk-data/opinions/wash.tar.gz

A sample JSON file within that archive (which contains 52,565 Washington State Supreme Court Judicial Opinions),

987095.json is an example with the following "elements" (I want to carry the element names over as column names while providing a new id for record count; rather than source database id column):

Using [Dadroit Viewer 1.5 Build 1935.appimage](https://dadroit.com/download) to view the JSON data easiest for me.

I extracted the following data (the bottom opinions_cited has [] brackets with 0 - 28 in them; and I expect each JSON to have different numbers of opinions_cited ; anyone from 0 to 1000 or more perhaps); I don't know the most cases cited in a Judicial Opinion.

**Extracted from JSON**:

```
resource_url 
id 
absolute_url 
cluster 
author 
joined_by 
author_str
per_curiam 
date_created 
date_modified 
type 
sha1 
page_count
download_url 
local_path 
plain_text 
html 
html_lawbox 
html_columbia
html_with_citations 
extracted_by_ocr
   
opinions_cited  (sub nodes) [0] - [28]
```

I need assistance in merging the directory (I tried various solutions found on google and stackoverflow for merging; none that I put against my cpu, memory or time has proven to work without taking for hours to error or produce nothing in the end).

How to I create 1 large CSV for every folder of JSONs (containing tens of thousands; in this example 54k) 1 JSON for every row in the CSV using JSON element names to create column's.

The StackOverFlow script I was using (code can be seen here to the error I posted in comments):

```py
import glob
import json

file_names = glob.glob('*.json')

json_list = []

for curr_f_name in file_names:
    with open(curr_f_name) as curr_f_obj:
        json_list.append(json.load(curr_f_obj))

with open('json_merge_out.json', 'w') as out_file:
    json.dump(json_list, out_file, indent=4)
```

The above attempt remedy outputs the following error:

```
/Wash/json# ./json.merge.python.1.py
./json.merge.python.1.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./json.merge.python.1.py: line 4: `file_names = glob.glob('*.json')'
```

Comment: Looking back at my last attempt to solve this: I found this code on Stackoverflow (I will share the URL if I can locate it):#
/Wash/json# ./json.merge.python.1.py
./json.merge.python.1.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./json.merge.python.1.py: line 4: `file_names = glob.glob('*.json')'
#

Comment: What are the [CODE] tags for? these don't work on SO unfortunately.

Comment: @rv.kvetch , What should I be using instead of [CODE] tags ?

Comment: The formatting is the same as GitHub markdown, from what I can tell. So you'd use triple backticks ``` to wrap your code instead.

Comment: @rv.ketch Thank you! Worked perfect! :)

Comment: FYI, the syntax error message from `./json.merge.python.1.py` means it's being run as a shell script not a Python script. Generally, that means you didn't give it a correct shebang (the shebang is the first line, which should start with something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` to tell the operating system what kind of script it is; filename extensions like `.py` do not have any meaning or use on UNIX, and should only be present for libraries, not executables).

Comment: Alternately, if you run `python json.merge.python.1.py`, that will for the script to be run with a Python interpreter, which likewise will avoid the problem of the operating system not knowing how to run the script and running it with a shell interpreter... but really, the right thing is to give your Python script a shebang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fast solution using jq.  It requires hardly any memory, but there is general caveat and one potential complication.

The caveat is that it has been assumed that the "joined_by" array can be flattened into a string using "; " as a separator.

The complication is that some CSV parsers require a "rectangular" structure.  In the first potential solution below, the header that is generated will only take into account the length of the
"opinions_cited" array in the first file that is presented.  If later JSON files contain more
"opinions_cited", the rows will still be correct, but the header will not take them into account.

If the header is an issue, then you might wish to consider a two-pass solution to avoid memory issues.  As shown in Part 2 of this answer, the first pass would be responsible for
determining the maximum array length,
and in the second pass, this value would be used to determine the appropriate headers.

You might also wish to consider a post-processing "fixup".

For testing, I'd suggest using a truncated version of `topKeys`, e.g.

```
def topKeys: {resource_url, opinions_cited};
```

### Part 1 - a one-pass approach

The following has been tested with this invocation of jq in the directory in which all the .json files reside:

```sh
jq -Mnrf combine.jq *.json > wash.csv
```

#### combine.jq

```
def topKeys: {
  resource_url,
  id,
  absolute_url,
  cluster,
  author,
  joined_by,
  author_str,
  per_curiam,
  date_created,
  date_modified,
  type,
  sha1,
  page_count,
  download_url,
  local_path,
  plain_text,
  html,
  html_lawbox,
  html_columbia,
  html_with_citations,
  extracted_by_ocr
}
  | .joined_by |= (if type == "array" then join("; ") else . end)
;

def header:
 (topKeys|keys_unsorted) + [range(1; 1 + (.opinions_cited | length)) ];

def row:
  [topKeys[]] + .opinions_cited;

# s should be a stream of arrays
# For each item in the stream, a counter (starting at 1) is inserted before the other items
def insert_counter(s): foreach s as $x (0; .+1; [.] + $x);

# Read the first file for the headers
input
| (["record"] + header),
   insert_counter( (., inputs) | row )
| @csv
```

### Part 2 - a two-pass solution

(a) Change the def of `header` above to:

```
def header:
 (topKeys|keys_unsorted) + [range(1; 1 + $n) ];
```

(b) Use or adapt the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$(jq 'def max(s): reduce s as $x (null; if . == null or $x > . then $x else . end); max(.opinions_cited|length)' *.json )

jq -Mnr --argjson n $n -f combine.jq *.json > wash.csv
```

#### For the record...

There are many post-processing alternatives.  One is to use [csvq](https://github.com/mithrandie/csvq), e.g.:

```
csvq --allow-uneven-fields -f CSV 'select *' < wash.csv | sponge wash.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code with implemented requirements of mine for this hurdle. I am currently running your jq script and it's showing me the contents of each json file... does it spit a csv in the running directory after the script is run? or does it need more code to write the data parsed to the @csv?

Comment: it finished with the following "62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c" after the script finished and that was the next part of tcsh. I don't see any files within the working directory. I don't believe it worked. Read the files... no outputs. Thanks again for the assistance!

Comment: @BrandonEVT, this code doesn't create output files -- you're expected to use shell redirection to direct the output to a file.

Comment: CharlesDuffy, I did not know this. I have never read the term shell redirection until just now. I was hoping it merged all the .JSON folders to 1 .json. I only mentioned CSV because of the @CSV code in the adjusted example for my case! However I know I can import CSV into DB Browser (Sqlite) in LXDE/Debian 10; merging all the .json files data to a single CSV would solve this feat also! Thank you again everyone for the help!

Comment: @BrandonEVT, ...to give you a concrete example of redirecting stdout, `jq -Mnrf combine.jq *.json >out.csv` will create `out.csv`.

Comment: CharlesDuffy , I used the above code from peak with your >out.csv and created a .combined.csv (which worked; accumulated 1GB). However once it became a CSV. I cannot import it into SQLite by Command Line or Import CSV using the DB Linux Browser without errors. 49 columns set with 150 or so actually.  Is there a way to capture all the 150ish columns, rather than the 49 I pulled originally out of the selected .json for example. (Turns out I was wrong). More than 49 (anyway to do a non-set combine.jq for columns expected to capture all the data and dismiss any errors) ? TY peak and CharlesDuffy

Comment: @BrandonEVT - I've added details about a two-pass solution.

Comment: @peak Thank you very much! I have implemented the changes and I run the following: ```./script.sh
jq: Could not open 10: No such file or directory``` (When running ./script.sh ... everything is background and then the wash.csv is created with 0 bytes.) Eventually it produces the output of Could not open 10: No such file or directory and that's it.

Comment: @peak I do not know if the "for the record" addition (which is great information by the way) ... is that the solution for the problem I was facing running the .csv produced document with your code by running a post operation against the csv file produced which *could* then allow SQLite DB Browser Import - csv - (possible w/o errors) or MariaDB command line? Thanks 100% ... I was following along and then once the csv became the json files, I couldn't do anything without errors. I also do not know how to properly communicate on here it seems. Sorry!